# How do I code the following without changing the original code?

Tags: python, deque

My task is to write a code that circularly shifts the values of the four variables (a,b,c,d). I am not allowed to make use of more than one new variable to accomplish the task. For example, if the variable values of (a,b,c,d) are initially 11, 21, 31 and 41 respectively, then the final values of (a,b,c,d) should be 41, 11, 21 and 31 respectively. I am also not allowed to make changes the original code.

```
# given code
a = 11  
b = 21 
c = 31 
d = 41 
print('before rotation: a =', a, 'b =', b, 'c =', c, 'd =',d) 

# the code that i wrote
import collections

var = collections.deque([a, b, c, d])  
var.rotate(1)  # to the right

# given code
print('after rotation: a =', a, 'b =', b, 'c =', c, 'd =', d)
```

I expect the output to be:

```
before rotation: a = 11 b = 21 c = 31 d = 41
after rotation: a = 41 b = 11 c = 21 d = 31
```

but I got:

```
before rotation: a = 11 b = 21 c = 31 d = 41
after rotation: a = 11 b = 21 c = 31 d = 41
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're rotating `var`, a `deque` object whose value is completely separate from those of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, with which you use to initialize `var`, so changes made to `var`'s value would not be reflected on the values of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

You can unpack `var` as an iterable by assigning it to `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` as a tuple instead:

```
a, b, c, d = var
```

Alternatively, you can simply rotate the tuple yourself by hard-coding the rotated tuple:

```
a, b, c, d = d, a, b, c
```